# Why is pd.concat({}, axis=1) slower than pd.concat({}, axis=0).unstack(0)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider this dictionary of pandas series.  The index on all series are integers and have some potential overlap, but certainly do not coincide.  I made an observation that `pd.concat` seems slow when combining things along `axis=1` when I have large indices, lots of non-overlap, and many items to concatenate.  It prompted me to leave `axis=0` and subsequently `unstack()`.  I end up with the same exact result.  But unstacking is quicker.

Does anyone have a handle on why this would be the case?

I get that concatenating series on top of one another should be quick, but I would have guessed that the unstacking processes would have been near identical as `pd.concat(axis=1)`.

```
dict_of_series = {
    's%s' % i: pd.Series(
        1, np.unique(np.random.randint(1000, 10000, size=1000))
    ) for i in range(100)
}
```

---

```
%%timeit
pd.concat(dict_of_series, axis=0).unstack(0)
```

> 10 loops, best of 3: 29.6 ms per loop

```
%%timeit
pd.concat(dict_of_series, axis=1)
```

> 10 loops, best of 3: 43.1 ms per loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick profiling shows that a lot of time in the call `pd.concat(dict_of_series, axis=1)` is consumed by `pd.Index.union`. It is called on each index one by one inside an internal function `_union_indexes` - similarly as in my function `union` below.

On the other hand, `pd.concat(dict_of_series, axis=0).unstack(0)` makes use of some clever optimization, which I didn't try to analyze. Anyway, there is no call to `_union_indexes` or even `pd.Index.union` there.

Can '_union_indexes' be a culprit? Very likely. I took just the indexes:

```
idxs = [d.index for d in dict_of_series.values()]
```

and compared the following two functions:

```
def union(idxs):
    ans = pd.Index([])
    for idx in idxs:
        ans = ans.union(idx)
    return ans

def union_multi(idxs):
    arr0 = np.concatenate(idxs)
    arr1 = np.zeros(arr0.size)
    ans = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([arr0, arr1])
    return ans.levels[0]
```

`union` is an equivalent of `_union_indexes`, while `union_multi` has some multi-index overhead but avoids a call to `pd.Index.union`.

My rough timings:

```
>>> %timeit -n1 -r1 pd.concat(dict_of_series, axis=1)
1 loop, best of 1: 82.9 ms per loop
>>> %timeit -n1 -r1 pd.concat(dict_of_series, axis=0).unstack(0)
1 loop, best of 1: 57.9 ms per loop

>>> %timeit -n1 -r1 union(idxs)
1 loop, best of 1: 32.8 ms per loop
>>> %timeit -n1 -r1 union_multi(idxs)
1 loop, best of 1: 12.5 ms per loop
```

A simple `pd.Index(np.unique(np.concatenate(idxs)))` is slightly faster but it doesn't work for mixed types.

(BTW, `pd.concat` works only if all indexes are unique.)